# How to build ajax paths for .cfc files in a plugin?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

In my plugin, I have defined a custom remote function. Here are the contents:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
<cffunction name="getPersons" access="remote" output="false">
<cfset var local = {}>

<cfquery name="local.getPersons" >
  SELECT FirstName FROM Persons
</cfquery>
<cfreturn local.getPersons>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

This function is defined in file mytest.cfc that is stored under displayObjects/cfc directory.

In my main.cfm file that is stored in displayObjects directory, I need to make a ajax call to the function in mytest.cfc.

I am wondering how can I build proper path.

Calling `#$.getCurrentURL()#` returns:

```
 http://localhost:8888/mymura/default/
```

However, I would somehow need to build and specify the following specify URL path to my ajax query:

```
http://localhost:8888/mymura/plugins/MyTest1_2/displayObjects/cfc/mytest.cfc
```

Can someone please tell me what is the recommended way to store plugin-specific .cfc files and how to properly build full path to access them?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

EDIT: I am almost there:

```
<cfoutput>
  <a href="#$.currentURL() & pluginConfig.getDirectory()#/displayObjects/cfc/myquery.cfc">My other file</a>
</cfoutput>
```

This returns:

```
http://localhost:8888/mymura/default/MyTest1_2/displayObjects/cfc/mytest.cfc
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost:8888/mymura/plugins/MyTest1_2/displayObjects/cfc/mytest.cfc
```

Method `$.currentURL()` returns `localhost:8888/mymura/default`. I just need to find a way to traverse up one directory and append "plugins."

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the URL using the domain setting of the site:

```
$.siteConfig().getDomain() & "/plugins/" & pluginConfig.getDirectory() & /displayObjects/cfc/myquery.cfc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. $.siteConfig().getDomain() returns just "localhost." I would need "localhost:8888/mymura." Is there some other method I can call? Regards.